# Modifying d3js parsets reusable chart

Tags: d3.js, charts, visualization

I am new to D3js and working with the parsets reusable chart (http://www.jasondavies.com/parallel-sets/). I want to make changes to this chart such as adding sort based on thickness of ribbons on mouseover, and overlaying two parallel sets over each other to compare different datasets at once (The one at the back being faded).

Being new to D3js, I am having difficulty in understanding where to start. I am currently trying to understand the code of d3.parsets.js but its not going too well. If anyone has worked with this before and understands the procedure being followed in the code, please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

The best adaptation I've seen of d3.parsets.js is by Hongjian Yang: [Airline Vis adapted from d3.parsets](http://hacker-yhj.github.io/projects/vis_course_assignment/).
It may be able to accomplish some of what you're looking for, though I'm not sure you'll readily be able to overlay two datasets (nor am I sure I understand the need to do so).